# mips code solutions - found error myself

Tags: mips

```
    .data
    .word 5
    .word 4
    .word 3
    .word 2
    .word 1
    .text 
    .globl main

    addi $t5, $zero, 0x10010000 #base address - 0x10010000
    main:
    Loop:
    addi $t0, $t0, 0
    bge $t0, 5, Exit
    sll $t1,$t1,2
    add $t2, $t5, $t1
    lw $t3, 0($t2)
    sll $t3,$t3,1
    sw $s0, 0($t3)
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    j Loop
    Exit:
```

The error I discovered was in sw $s0, 0($t3). The exception is the following: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x0000000a. Based on this error, it looks like there is no word alignment. What is the best way to fix the error?

Your feedback (or constructive criticism) is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sw $s0, 0($t3)` makes no sense at all. `$s0` has not been initialized, and `$t3` contains a value in the range 2..10. Did you mean `sw $t3,($t2)`? Or what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am looking to multiply each value in the array by two. The final result should be the following: [10. 8, 6, 4, 2]. The multiplication works, but saving the new values is causing the error. Do you have any ideas, besides what you had suggested, earlier? sw $t3,($t2) actually worked for me, but only for the first one. Also, I need to move i to proceed to the next value.

Comment: Forget what I said. I figured out my problem. All of the changes to i in the loop were being stored in the same register. Thank you so much! I appreciate your help!